# Are there any native callbacks from iOS while using splitView?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, split-screen-multitasking

I am using splitview. Upon change in width I want to trigger that width has been changed. Are there any callbacks available from iOS?

Comment: Check uisplitviewcontroller delegate class

Comment: I did not find any thing related to this in uisplitviewcontroller delegate class.

Comment: about which width you are talking, and when it is changing

Comment: I am talking about the change in width of primary and secondary app.When i change the width i want a callback.